# What happens if 2 wifi networks (run by different people) have the same SSID?

Tags: wireless-networking

so lets say theres 2 wifi networks run by 2 different people, they both have different passwords:

Wifi network 1 ssid: Example    Password: 9238
wifi network 2 ssid: Example    Password: 3234

If 2 networks have the same SSID, it shows the strongest connection in available networks right? So lets say I connect to wifi network 1 whilst it is the strongest, I then move closer to wifi network 2 however still in range of network 1. Does it try to connect to wifi network 2 even though the password is different?

Comment: it will show both ,why only stronger signal?

Comment: Have you done the experiment? Seems all you would need to do is set your WiFi SSID to match a neighbors and then see what happens when you move into range of their WiFi while still connected to yours.

Comment: @bodmaster I read a few posts online and they all said if the ssid's are the same then it connects to the stronger one.

Comment: @AMR I would love to do it but I am unable to where I live. I was just wondering if anyone knows just for my own curiosity. I'm not planning on using this information for anything I just thought of it and couldn't get it out of my head

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will attempt to connect to the one with the stronger SSID but will fail and go back to the one it can connect to. We had this issue at work before we centrally managed our Wireless APs and forgot to update the password for our guest network.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Just wondering, if there are 2 routers with same ssids and i was using my phone. It scans for networks and would show the nearest SSID correct? Not both?

Comment: Your phone will join the 2 SSIDs (usually) but will attempt to connect to either if one fails.

Comment: Oh, so if they aren't password protected it will connect to the strongest, and if they are password protected it will simply use the one that accepts the password

Comment: Generally yes. Depending on your phone operating system, it might jump to the strongest signal constantly or it might after polling every X seconds.